# index.jade not showing up any content

Tags: node.js, express

I screenshot the code to show the code indent. Previously I had error displaying on index.hade so, I remove the indent and the error gone. I did the same for layout.jade but the header went missing. SO I just leave it with indentation. But I've no clue as to why the contents of index.jade not showing up at all and not even error to denote?

layout.jade
[image]

index.jade
[image]

This is how it appears on web without textbox and button.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your indentation might be a bit off. Try copy and pasting the following:

**layout.jade**

```
doctype html
html
    block head
    title title
    link(href='/stylesheets/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css')
body
    header#banner
    h1 Awesome Chat
    block content
    footer Hope you enjoy your stay here
```

**index.jade**

```
extends ./layout
block content
    section#chatroom
    div#messages
    input#message(type="text" placeholder="Enter your message here")
    input#send(type="button" value="Send")
```

Comment: just the css not included now, but why again indentation problem?

Comment: @Keren Try removing commas from link. And make sure that link is indented with 4 spaces from left and is aligned with title.